# What is the difference when updating a deleted row and detached row?

Tags: c#, database, datatable

When deleting a row in a DataTable.

If I use `row.delete()` method then `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)`. It throws an Reference exception (don't notice this).

But if I use `Rows.remove(row)` method then `DataAdapter.Update(DataTable)`. It doesn't throw anything.

In both case, nothing changes in the database. I know in the 1st case the row is marked as deleted. And in the 2nd case, it's marked as detached.

Someone please explain to me what the DataAdapter do in each case.

Comment: Show your full code..

Comment: What database are you using, and yes show full code.

Comment: what type of exception do you get? it may be the result of the difference between delete and update. the first one needs to call accept change but the second one does not!